# Flotcharts, Excanvas and IE8: 'fillStyle' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, flot, excanvas

I am trying to use the [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org) JavaScript plotting library (version 0.8.2) and [excanvas.js](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to adapt it to IE8.

Calling `$.plot(plotPlaceholder, data, options);` I get the JS error **'fillStyle' is null or not an object** on excanvas.js, line 230, character 5, which corresponds to a snippet:

```
function copyState(o1, o2) {
    o2.fillStyle = o1.fillStyle;
    ...
}
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<head>
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        data = []
        data.push({data: [[63.62, 16.93]], label: 0, color: "red"});
        data.push({data: [[56.1, 13.11]], label: 1, color: "blue"});
        data.push({data: [[30, 13]], label: 2, color: "green"});

        var options = {};
        plotPlaceholder = ".results-container";
        var plot = $.plot(plotPlaceholder, data, options);
    });
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="plot-container">
            <div class="results-container" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; margin:auto;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd check that the excanvas.js is actually being loaded first. Also, you don't need to (and probably shouldn't) just test for IE. Flot works fine with IE 9 without excanvas, so you should test the version number as suggested in the [Flot readme](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Are you using IE8, or a later version set to IE8 render mode?

Comment: I am using IE8. I solved the problem by changing the conditional inclusion to `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->`, where excanvas.min.js comes from the development download of Flot library at www.flotcharts.org.